# ARIMA with difficult seasonality in R

Tags: time-series, trend, seasonality

I have non-stationary time series. It has evident trend in means and seasonality. These raw data are measured every second. On the plot of original series I see trend and seasonality about 80,81 (after each 80 second we can see new growth). It is possible that I will never obtain model with white noise? I have tried first difference and first seasonal difference on 80 and second seasonal difference with 81 pediod, and twice of 81. And stiil I have regular data in residuals! It is possible??

I have used R. I have tried different ways: step-by-step, ARIMA with different settings for differences, auto.arima. I do not know why I cannot receive white noise in the residuals. I look on ACF of residuals.

Has the task got solution?

Below I present my data.

```
3785
4542
4542
4542
4542
4542
4542
4542
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
4731
5772
8043
8516
8516
8516
8516
8516
8516
8516
8516
8516
8516
8516
8516
8516
8516
8516
8705
8705
8705
8705
8705
8705
8705
8705
8705
8705
8800
8800
8800
8800
8800
8800
8800
8800
8800
8800
8800
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
8989
10314
12585
13058
13058
13058
13058
13058
13058
13058
13058
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
13247
14288
16843
17032
17032
17032
17032
17032
17032
17032
17032
17032
17032
17032
17032
17032
17032
17032
17032
17032
17032
17032
17032
17316
17316
17316
17316
17316
17316
17316
17316
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
17505
18073
21101
21290
21290
21290
21290
21290
21290
21290
21290
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21574
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
21763
25359
25548
25548
25548
25548
25548
25548
25548
25548
25548
25548
25548
25548
25548
25548
25548
25548
25548
25548
25548
25548
25548
25832
25832
25832
25832
25832
25832
25832
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
26021
29333
30090
30090
30090
30090
30090
30090
30090
30090
30090
30090
30090
30090
30090
30090
30090
30090
30279
30279
30279
```

Comment: Your data has the series of repeating values. By construction ARIMA processes cannot have such values, hence it is no suprise that you are not able to get white noise in the residuals.

Comment: Looks like a step data when plotted. You might want to use some sort of step function(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function) to model this type of data. Also you can check out digital signal processing in engineering,  where this type of data can be handled easily using tools like MATLAB.

Comment: @mpiktas yes, data has series of repeating values, but they are not regular. I can decompose the series to trend component, seasonal component and reminders. Do you think that I can model the reminders by ARIMA and look for white noise? It could make sense? By the way, ARIMA predicts future values of this series quite good.

Comment: @forecaster, I would like to decompose the series into trend, seasonal and white noise and maybe something else (as I have written above). Are you sure that only step function is proper way for this forecasting?

Comment: @KateRin step function might be one of the approach that you can use, it certainly is not the only way. How is this data collected, I'm assuming some type of sensor, if the data is collected every second, you might want to approch this probelm using signal processing vs. statistical time series analysis. I may be wrong, but there might be better approaches in statistics that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @forecaster, thank you. The data is quite abstract. It is result some function. I have obtained time series and I would like to forecast it by classical statistic method (like ARIMA with which predicts this series good). In the other side, I do not belive that I cannot make further analysis and estimate residuals in direction of white noise searching. But after that it is necessary to sum all components in one mathematical equation.

Comment: I have now uploaded the pictures of all the induvidual components +forecast.

Comment: You could also try the `ets` and `tbats` functions in the forecast package.

Comment: @Zach, thank you, I have tried `tbats`, but I obtained similar results - problem with cleaning of regularity (white noise). I am affraid that this serie need multiple seasonality 79,80,81 and other. I will look on the `ets`. This series is very headstrong!

Comment: `tbats` is expressly built to handle multiple seasonalities, e.g. `tbats(x, seasonal.periods=c(79, 80, 81))`.

Comment: @Zach R works with your command already 15 minutes (a lot of memory is needed).

Comment: @KateRin can you explain what you mean by "first seasonal difference on 80 and second seasonal difference with 81 pediod, and twice of 81"

Comment: @Zach I have results. Residuals are still correlated around multiplies 80 lags. I will check another settings in `tbats'.

Comment: @forecaster, It means: `diff(diff(series,80),81)` and `diff(diff(series,81),81)`.

Comment: But there is other problem yet. Series seems to be not seasonal on lags 81,162,243,..; it is seasonality on 81,161,241,.... Such shift? But 80,160,240 seems to be ok.

Comment: if you know this apriori, why don't you use an exogenous indicator variable for seasonality ?

Comment: @forecaster, What is this? I do know all methods. Thank you for direction.

Comment: @forecaster, Ok, I have found. It means seasonal dummies. I will try to use it. Thank you.

Comment: @forecaster, it does not work :( It is not dummies, but random data. All values cannot be tractable like outliers. I do not belive that I cannot obtain white noise in any manner. First difference is stationary. We see trend an seasonal component. Why I cannot extract white noise from the remainders? Is there any brutal method?

Comment: If it is random data then I would assume you would not be able to model with any method. Can you explain what is the objective of your analysis, what is the type of data, what function was used to generate the data.

Comment: @forecaster, I do not understand. All modeled data are random. But we can always try to find such regular pattern and residuals. As you see on your below analysis, you can predict future values even. I have different models but residuals have significant values and it is bad. I think that knowledge about process which has generated my data is not significant. But I understand that it can be interesting. I have agent on network device and it capture events, counts them and writes result. As you see, data are quite regular and some fluctuations can be observed.

Comment: It is non-stationary time series which can be change to stationary and I have to find the model.

Comment: Each Arima model show heavy tailed distribution of residuals. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if ARIMA would be able to decompose the data into interprettable/decomposed time series.

I used [Proc UCM](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_ucm_sect006.htm) in SAS which is a state space model. Following is the code of a basic structural model. The data is decomposed into Trend (level+slope) + Seasonal and White noise (Irregular). There is not much white noise left after you model. I'm assuming this is what you were looking for. The model fits the data like a glove. If you have access to SAS, you can try running the following code, you can get the decomposed series.

Level + Slope+ Seasonal + Irregular (not Shown).

[image]

[image: Forecast Output which is comination of level+slope+season:]

[image]

You could also try `STL decomposition` in R.

ods graphics on;
       proc ucm data = data;

```
      id date interval = second; 
      model value;
      irregular plot = smooth;
      level ;
      slope variance = 0 noest;
      season length = 80 ;
       dep lags = 2;
      forecast plot=(forecasts decomp) lead = 80 outfor=forecast; 
   run ; 
ods graphics off ;
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: it is very promissing. Thank you. Could you attach ACF of residuals yet, please? It will show if residuals are white noise.

Comment: @KateRin you mentioned that this is a result of some function. Based on the output that I see, I don't see any major residuals at all. Dis you add a random noise to the data from the function, if not then you cannot expect any residuals. As mentioned it is a somewhat a good fit. The code that I provided is a very basic code you can improve it to get more robust fit for your data.

Comment: Hmm, but remainders did you receive? You have written: Irregular component not shown. Could you attach this component?

Comment: I expressed poorly. The function, which I used, has random input. If you have daily data, then you have prepared weekly data in based simple sum of vales of 7 days. Therefore my series is stochastic process and I expect reminders/residuals. It is proper thinking?

Comment: In R I have received remainder of STL.

Comment: see attached, I have included ACF of residulas. Of course the model can be improved with lags of 80/81 which is easy to do in proc ucm. you can alos adjust for any outliers.

Comment: Even more precisely, I hoped to decompose reminder per such new component plus white noise. Problem is that this serie semms to be multiseasonal series.

Comment: Thank you. You have still significant values on 80,160,240,... lags. "you can alos adjust for any outliers" you think that remainder can be decomposed again in the same manner?

Comment: In PROC UCM can easily incorporate multiple seasonal lengths easily and complex seasonal patterns such as this one http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_ucm_sect042.htm

Comment: UCM above did a fine job, there is no significant values left. I agree that the values at 79 and 81 are slight outside the 2 standar errors, but this could be improved if you refine the UCM model, dod you try it ?

Comment: I meant to say, there is no significant auto correlation of residuals left, but this model could be slightly improved with refining UCM.

Comment: I do not belive! No significant pattern on residuals ACF? Have you checked for 300 lags? I have not got SAS licence unfortunately :(